# Dynamic allocation, default constructor and virtual tables

Tags: c++, constructor

I have some questions.

1. If I have a class A and I create an instance through: `A* a = new A()`;
   I see that the constructor is called twice. 
   It doesn't make sense. I'm a programmer create this object only once and hence I suppose that the constructor will be called only once, Isn't it?
   What is the difference between `A* a = new A`, and `A* = new A()`?
2. What is exact the default constructor? If I have a constructor in my class A which takes no parameters, is it the default constructor? Or is it the constructor if I don't declare a constructor with no parameters?
3. If I have class B inherit from A, and there is a function called `foo` in A, B.
   What is the difference in the virtual table if `foo` is virtual and `foo` is not virtual?

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't know what you [mean](http://ideone.com/XSAvWZ), its only called once.

2) Yes the default constructor is the constructor that takes no parameters. If you do not declare one, the compiler will generate one, however it may not be the one you desire.

3) If `foo` is virtual in `A`, dynamic binding will apply. It will not if `foo` is not virtual.

```
A *a = new B();
a->foo(); //will call b::foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. A constructor should only be called once, post the code so what can see what's happening. There is no difference between `A* a = new A` and `A* a = new A()`.
2. A default constructor is one that takes no arguments or has all default parameters. If you don't define one for your class, the compiler will provide one for **only if** you haven't defined another constructor that takes arguments.
3. If `foo` isn't declared virtual, there will be no virtual table; the compiler will insert the actual function address at compile time in places where `foo` is called. If it is virtual, the compiler generates some code to look up the address of the function in the virtual table based on the object type on which `foo` is being called.